# MS Access Script Conversion to T-Sql script

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access

Can i use nested Case statements in t-sql as i have done and also "*" used for multiplcation in the access query can it be used in the same way in T-sql for example

```
([Col2]*[col3])
```

MS Access:

```
IIf(IsNull([Col1]),([Col2]*[col3]),([col2]*[col3]/[col1])) as Column
```

T-Sql:

```
Case When [Col1] Is Null then ([Col2]*[col3]) 
else ([col2]*[col3]/[col1]) end AS column
```

Ms Access:

```
IIf(Left([col],1)=3,"Tran",IIf(Left([ss],1)=7,"Con","Sto")) AS [col]
```

T-sql:

```
(Case When (Left([col],1)=3) then 'Tran' else (Case When (Left([col],1)=7) then 'Con' else 'Sto' end )end) AS [col type]
```

Comment: " MS Access "#" wildcard " - it's not a wildcard, it's a date marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd TSQ should look like this:

```
CASE 
 WHEN LEFT([col],1)=3 THEN 'Tran'
 WHEN LEFT([col],1)=7 THEN 'Con'
 ELSE 'Sto' 
END  AS [col type]
```

As far as `#` you don't need that in SQL, just put the date value in single quotes correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks for your response and pointing a simple query rather than mine